# Regex To Exclude The First Word

Tags: regex, email, replace, notepad++

**Scenario**

Recently I extracted emails from 430 different html webpages of organizations with regex but some organizations had multiple emails and here's what the mess looks like

**Input**

```
   Organization 2

     info@something.org.au more@something.com market@gmail.com single@noidea.com human@myplace.com south@north.com darlings@mall.com 


   Organization 3

  headmistress@money.com head@skull.com
```

**What I want**
The very first email of these organizations is the important email. Is there any way regex can select everything after the first whole word and I can use Notepad++'s "Replace All" to remove it?

**Output(Something like this)**

```
   Organization 2

     info@something.org.au


   Organization 3

  headmistress@money.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your expected output, use this pattern:

```
/^.*?@[^ ]+|^.*$/gm
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kN3eR5/1)

Answer (score 0):

- step 1:
          first you have to keep all email address in a variable as string.
- step 2:
          split your string to array
- step 3:
         get your first email id based on array index.

check the example code below:

```
    var emailIds = "info@something.org.au more@something.com market@gmail.com,  single@noidea.com human@myplace.com south@north.com darlings@mall.com";

    var emailInArray = emailIds.split(' ');

    console.log(emailInArray[0]) //info@something.org.au;
```